# Using JS to animate a circle stroke when in view

Tags: javascript, canvas, scroll, jquery-animate, stroke

I am trying to generate a site with interactive elements and animations.  I have came across [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/uhVj6/4/) which is perfect for what I need.

I want the circle to start animating when the canvas element is visible in the browser, or possibly when a certain scroll point has been reached (ie: > 1000 px in the Y direction- start animation).

I am completely new to JS, so have tried to piece together code from other sources with no luck.  I have tried (in context with the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/uhVj6/4/)):

```
// requestAnimationFrame Shim
(function() {
  var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                              window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
  window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
})();


var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
 var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
 var x = canvas.width / 2;
 var y = canvas.height / 2;
 var radius = 75;
 var endPercent = 85;
 var curPerc = 0;
 var counterClockwise = false;
 var circ = Math.PI * 2;
 var quart = Math.PI / 2;

 context.lineWidth = 10;
 context.strokeStyle = '#ad2323';
 context.shadowOffsetX = 0;
 context.shadowOffsetY = 0;
 context.shadowBlur = 10;
 context.shadowColor = '#656565';


 function animate(current) {
     context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
     context.beginPath();
     context.arc(x, y, radius, -(quart), ((circ) * current) - quart, false);
     context.stroke();
     curPerc++;
     if (curPerc < endPercent) {
         requestAnimationFrame(function () {
             animate(curPerc / 100)
         });
     }
 }


// My altered code to the original
   $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($('#myCanvas').is(':visible')) {
        .animate();
    }
});
```

But this is doing nothing.  I would imagine this to be a relatively simple problem for those in the know.  But I haven't a clue!

Look forward to your answers, apologies if I have missed anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include Jquery in your fiddle. That was giving you an error if your going to try and use it for `scroll()` Also you dont need the `.` in front of `animate()`. Also give your body a height that you can scroll on your else youll never activate it. See my fiddle for the changes

http://jsfiddle.net/uhVj6/220/

Comment: Thanks for your response Keirchon.  I looked at your fiddle, but it doesn't seem to work.  The moment I scroll down the animation quickly appears then disappears. I'm using the latest version of chrome.

Comment: @RichardTeahan just scroll down once and wait then it works once you scroll again it disappears. I dont know why that happens still trying to figure that one out

Comment: @RichardTeahan Fixed it!! Animate is being called too many times it should one be called once so i put a conditional in there so it only runs once. http://jsfiddle.net/uhVj6/219/

Comment: @RichardTeahan it actually animates the second any scroll is initialized. But I fixed it to the way you want http://jsfiddle.net/uhVj6/220/

Comment: A lot of these little fixes I'm doing by just googling certain questions and copying code. Like for the last one I googled "jquery determine if element is visible on screen" found one that mentioned scrolling and just copied that code directly then incorporated it into the conditional. Try and do the same before relying so much on stackoverflow. It will help you learn a lot more and give you good practice on searching resources on your own

Comment: Keirchon your quick response has been a saviour! Don't worry, I do normally try and google alot of things before asking others.  Sadly JS is just another language I need to learn, sooner rather than later! Much appreciated!

Comment: @RichardTeahan Youre welcome. Youll get the hang of it through practice. Took me over a year till I would say I fully know it and Im still learning new tricks on here every day

Answer (score 0):

call your `animate();` in this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    called = false;
    $(window).scroll(function (e) {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > $("canvas").position().top && !called){
            animate();
            called = true;
        }
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uhVj6/223/